# Finding the first few digits of p and q

Tags: rsa, factoring

Is there a way to find out the first few digits of the factors of the [RSA numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_numbers) (RSA-1024 or RSA-2048)?

I do not want to get all the digits but only first 4-5 digits. My question is thus more precisely:

Is there a known, efficient, classical algorithm, that given a composite number, outputs the 4-5 most significant decimal digits of one of the prime factors of this number?

Answer (score 4):

I do not think this is a practical possibility. In order to get the 4-5 most significant bits, the bits of lower significance must be known. This is due to the manner in which numbers are multiplied. The most significant bits of the product do not depend solely on the most significant bits of the factors. Bits of lower significance may have an effect too due to the propagation of carry bits up the product as partial products are summed. Even with some look-ahead optimizations the bits of lower significance would still need to be known. The best I could see would be a probabilistic scheme in which k>5 bits would would be attempted to be solved and the result would be probabilistically correct with some chance as a function of k.

Comment: Would this method be efficient- i,e would it run in polynomial time?  Also can the probability of error be reduced to an arbitrarily low value with a polynomial runtime? In other words is this method in the complexity class BPP?

Comment: I've not tried anything of this sort previously, however my intuition is that it would be doable in polynomial time. If you've got an RSA key of 1024 or 2048 bits, I would anticipate that the top 45 bits, implying k = 40, would be sufficient for the probabilistic aspect of the correctness.

Comment: This method would not work however for Mersenne Primes due to their special form. I just realized that.

Comment: Thanks, I found it strange that no one has  tried it out on RSA numbers to figure out the first few digits.

Comment: Loads of people have tried loads of things. This problem is one part of the P=NP question/debate. This problem is assumed to be NP, and NP is assumed to not equal P.  Factoring integers being in P or P=NP both seem unlikely given the amount of research gone into their investigation, but neither has a proof of their non-equivalence been forthcoming given the copious amounts of research.

Comment: @poncho I think you mean factorization is not NP-complete. It's certainly NP as the factors are witnesses.

Comment: @KenGoss: do you mind sharing the details of your probabilistic scheme?  I can't think of any practical way (that is better than just guessing based on the size of the ranges of the possible $p, q$ values)

Comment: @poncho Consider the most significant bit (msb). It is the result of the and between the msb's of the two factors xor'd with the and of the ands of the 2nd and 3rd most significant bits. For a product $p$ and two, four bit factors, $a$ and $b$, $p_3=(a_3b_3)\oplus ( (b_2a_3)(b_3a_2))$. This grows in complexity the further you go into the result, but I hope that gives some intuition of how to proceed.

Comment: @KenGoss: actually, it's also a function of carries from lower in the multiplication.  I suspect that as you consider those factors, it'll turn out that your probabilistic scheme won't end up telling you anything nontrivial...

Comment: Yes they will have an influence, each with decreasing probability as distance from the most significant bit increases, I was attempting to keep the example simple and intuitive while staying within the comment character limit. At most this will return a set of probable solutions which are expected to be a proper subset of the potential search space.